# Boundary Estimation Error

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to extract boundary points from point cloud,and want to print the boundary points.Unfortunately, I got error like error C2248: 'pcl::BoundaryEstimation<PointInT,PointNT,PointOutT>::computeFeature' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'pcl::BoundaryEstimation<PointInT,PointNT,PointOutT>'. Did anybody experience this? Thanx in advance.

Here is my sample code.

```
int main (..) 
{ 
//Load point cloud 

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr normals (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>); 
pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> ne; 
ne.setInputCloud (cloud.makeShared()); 
pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ> ()); 
ne.setSearchMethod (tree); 
ne.setRadiusSearch (0.03); 
ne.compute (*normals); 

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Boundary> boundaries; 
pcl::BoundaryEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal, pcl::Boundary> est; 
est.setInputCloud (cloud.makeShared()); 
est.setInputNormals (normals); 
est.setRadiusSearch (0.03); 
est.setSearchMethod (pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>)); 
est.compute (boundaries); 

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Boundary>::Ptr boundary_cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Boundary> ()); 
est.computeFeature(*boundary_cloud); /// Error Here 
                
cout<<"Boundary Size:"<<boundaries.points.size()<<endl; 
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61971/boundary-estimation-error./) by [Nihad](https://answers.ros.org/users/4554/nihad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2013-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As shown [here](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/boundary_8h_source.html), the `computeFeature` call is a protected member of the `BoundaryEstimation` class, so you are not able to call this method from your code.  You can see in the [source](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/feature_8hpp_source.html) for `compute` that `computeFeature` is called by the publicly-accessible `compute` method.  So, it should be sufficient to just call `compute`.

Try just removing these lines:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Boundary>::Ptr boundary_cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Boundary> ()); 
est.computeFeature(*boundary_cloud); /// Error Here
```

---

**Edit:**
I believe that pcl::BoundaryEstimation only returns a boolean flag for whether or not a given point is on the boundary.  You'll need to access the original point cloud to get the XYZ coordinates of matching points:

```
for (int i=0; i<cloud.size(); i++)
  if (boundaries.points[i].boundary_point == 1)
    cout << cloud.points[i];
```

If you are seeing garbage values when printing out boundary_point values, it may be because BoundaryEstimation can't find the nearest-neighbors in your point cloud.  In this case, it sets boundary_point to NaN (which may look like "garbage" when printed.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nihad](https://answers.ros.org/users/4554/nihad/) on 2013-05-02**:
Thank you. But how can I access boundary point`s x, y and z coordinate information? I use following line  but it gave garbage value.
for (size_t i = 0; i < boundaries.points.size (); ++i)
std::cerr << "    " << boundaries.points[i].boundary_point<<endl;